# Solve differential equation with constant

Tags: differential-equations

How can I get a symbolic solution from the following differential equation?
I don't know in that case using a change of variable is a good idea.
I have tried in maple as well but the form of the solution was not in my desire.

```
wave = (3 Derivative[1][a][t]/a[t] Derivative[1][T][t]) + 
   T[t] (\[CapitalOmega]^2/
      a[t]^2 - (6 Derivative[1][a][t]^2/
        a[t]^2) - (2 (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]/a[t])) + (
    T^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0
a[t_] := t^\[Alpha];
DSolve[(-((2 (-1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/t^2) - (6 \[Alpha]^2)/t^2 + 
      t^(-2 \[Alpha]) \[CapitalOmega]^2) T[t] + (
   3 \[Alpha] Derivative[1][T][t])/t + (T^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 
  0, {T[t], T[t]}, {t}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is `wave` for? where is it used?

Comment: `It's gravitational waves` OK. But why do you have it is my question. Where is it used in the `DSolve` command? If it is not relevant variable and not used, why show it in the question? It can make things confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 8):

**DSolve** can solve if we perform some algebraic manipulations:

```
eq = (-((2 (-1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/t^2) - (6 \[Alpha]^2)/t^2 + 
 t^(-2 \[Alpha]) \[CapitalOmega]^2) T[t] + (3 \[Alpha] T'[t])/t + T''[t];
eq1 = (eq*t^2 // Simplify // Expand) == 0
```

$$\Omega ^2 t^{2-2 \alpha } T(t)+t^2 T''(t)+3 \alpha  t T'(t)-8 \alpha ^2 T(t)+2 \alpha  T(t)=0$$

If we change exponent from: $2-2 \alpha$ to $z$ then:

```
 eq3 = 2 \[Alpha] T[t] - 8 \[Alpha]^2 T[t] + 
t^z \[CapitalOmega]^2 T[t] + 3 t \[Alpha] T'[t] + t^2 T''[t] == 0;
DSolve[eq3, T[t], t] /. z -> 2 - 2 \[Alpha] // FullSimplify
(*Go back from z to 2-2 \alpha*)
```

$$T(t)=\left(t^{2-2 \alpha }\right)^{\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2 (-1+\alpha )}} (2-2 \alpha )^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{1-\alpha }} \Omega ^{\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{-1+\alpha }}
   \left(J_{\frac{\sqrt{1+\alpha  (-14+41 \alpha )}}{2-2 \alpha }}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t^{2-2 \alpha }} \Omega }{1-\alpha }\right) c_2 \Gamma \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{1+\alpha  (-14+41 \alpha )}}{2-2
   \alpha }\right)+J_{\frac{\sqrt{1+\alpha  (-14+41 \alpha )}}{2 (-1+\alpha )}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t^{2-2 \alpha }} \Omega }{1-\alpha }\right) c_1 \Gamma \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{1+\alpha  (-14+41
   \alpha )}}{2 (-1+\alpha )}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Just wow, well done ☺️

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica can't solve this

```
ClearAll[α, t, Ω, T]
ode = (-((2 (-1 + α) α)/t^2) - (6 α^2)/t^2 + t^(-2 α) Ω^2) T[t] + (3 α T'[t])/t + T''[t] == 0;
DSolve[ode, T[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It can however solve it when α is given a specific value

```
 DSolve[ode /. {α -> 1}, T[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 DSolve[ode /. {α -> 2}, T[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[ode /. {α -> 1/2}, T[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You said you tried Maple but did not like its solution. Why? Maple can solve this without given specific value for α and its solution agrees with Mathematica above for specific values of α :

```
local Omega:
ode := (-((2 (-1 + alpha)*alpha)/t^2) - (6*alpha^2)/t^2 + t^(-2* alpha)* Omega^2)*T(t)+ (3 *alpha* diff(T(t),t))/t + diff(T(t),t$2)= 0;
dsolve(ode)
```

[image]

This seems to be limitation of `DSolve` at this time.

Comment: @NajibeBorhani if the solution is valid, I am sure there is transformation of these special function to rewrite them in terms of other special functions. I mean you might be able to convert Maple's solution using Bessels's to the same as Mathematica's using Bessel and Gamma.  This becomes different issue.

Comment: @NajibeBorhani see [convert/to_special_functions](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=convert%2fto_special_function) at Maple's site. But there is no guarantee it will be able to convert the solution to the form you want but have to play with it and see.